# Using two tracking SDK in one application

Tags: ios, mobile, sdk, tracking, mat

We want to use TWO tracking SDKs with our iOS apps (they track installs and in-app events - e.g. Mobile app tracking). Are there any contraindications?

Comment: conflicts? contradictions? contractions?

Answer (score 0):

There must be no contradictions because that one tracking SDK will not effect the other one. But what is the use of having two tracking SDK's, Anyways if its not necessary avoid using two. There are a lot of tracking SDK's which are very much customizable to track everything.